# When will Arango support the JavaScript optional chaining operator?

Tags: arangojs

I have a number of newer JavaScript modules I would like to use with Arango. They use the conditional chaining operator (.?) and Arango fails to parse them when loading as part of a Foxx service. I am loathe to transpile them back to older JavaScript. Does anyone know when Arango will update its v8 engine?